# How to feed user input as an argument to an SQLite LIKE clause in Haskell

Tags: sqlite, haskell

In my program I have

```
search = do
    conn <- dbConnect
    let query = "SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE story LIKE '%engine%'"
    result <- quickQuery' conn query []
    mapM_ print(... )
    disconnect conn
```

this works and searches for the string and returns the complete field in which it occurs. I would like to be able to get the string from the user. The problem I am having is with the %. I know I need an argument for the search, but once I modify say, like this

```
search key  = do
conn <- dbConnect
    let query = "SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE story LIKE '%key%'"
    result <- quickQuery' coon query []
    mapM_ print(... )
   disconnect conn
```

I cannot find a way of passing any user input to it. There are no errors but it does not match to anything.
I have been trying to find something about this but I have had no luck. This is my first question, I hope I have provided enough details, if not let me know. Thanks for any advice.

```
quickQuery' :: IConnection conn => conn -> String -> [SqlValue] -> IO [[SqlValue]]
```

So quickQuery' takes a connection, a string (= sql query), and a list of parameters (= [SqlValue])
In my code I am not using replaceable parameters, so I am right in passing it []. 
But I now have also tried a version using replaceable parameters

```
search key  = do
    conn <- dbConnect
    let query = "SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE story LIKE (?)"
    result <- quickQuery' conn query [toSql key]
    mapM_ print(... )
    disconnect conn
```

It compiles but I am having the same problem as I really need the %key% otherwise it does not find the word I want it to find. The only way it will accept it is as "%key%" but then % becomes a normal character rather than a wild one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem.  Here is the code that works.

```
search key  = do
    conn <- dbConnect
    let query = "SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE story LIKE ('%' || ? || '%'?)"
    result <- quickQuery' conn query [toSql key]
    mapM_ print(... )
    disconnect conn
```

where the || operator is SQLite concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders use `?`, see http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html for example.

If you look at the signature `quickQuery :: IConnection conn => conn -> String -> [SqlValue] -> IO [[SqlValue]]`, you see `[SqlValue]` in there.

These are the replacement values you are looking ...

So how do you construct a SqlValue, let's see (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.1/docs/Database-HDBC.html#t:SqlValue):

There are a lot of constructors for this type, but I guess the one you want is `SqlString String`, as this is what your query is supposed to do

So at the end you need to modify your code looking like the following:

`search key  = do
conn <- dbConnect
    let query = "SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE story LIKE '%?%'"
    result <- quickQuery' coon query [SqlString key]
    mapM_ print(... )
   disconnect conn`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I have just tried that but I am now getting an error. Exception:SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "In HDBC execute, received [SqlString \"ambassador\"] but expected 0 args."}.

Comment: It is getting late where  I am. I will chew on this and get back to it in the morning.

Comment: following your comment I have tried using replaceable parameters in the code and I have updated my question.

Comment: Your solution still does not quite work. But I have figured it out now. Thanks.